# How to select the text between the curs and end of a cell in Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, selection

I have a table in Microsoft Word.
My cursor it's in the middle of a cell. I want, using vba, to select the text between the curs and the end of cell (NOT THE END OF THE LINE)

This is how you select the text between cursor and the end of the line

> Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub setMySelection()
    Set mySelection = Selection.Range
    mySelection.SetRange mySelection.Start, Selection.Cells(1).Range.End - 1
    mySelection.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Tested with word 2010.